# TypeError: Google is not a module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, youtube-api, ruby-1.8.7

Im trying to implement google youtube api in my ruby on rails project as stated in youtube documentation https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/ruby#retrieve_my_uploads so this block of code 
    require 'google/api_client'
I get the following error "TypeError: Google is not a module"

Comment: Have you restarted your server since installing the gem?  You'll need to.

Comment: Also can you include the relevant part of your code in your question?

Comment: @MaxWilliams yes I restarted it and tried to run the block of code in rails console and i get the same error,, this is the block of code [ require 'google/api_client' ]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the type of thing that will happen if you already have a class of your own called Google that isn't namespaced.

I had the same problem as you `TypeError: Google is not a module` and then upon further investigation discovered I had a class called Google that was getting loaded first.

Answer (score 0):

I faces same Problem like this :- `IndexOptions is not a module (TypeError)`

After investigate the issues i found a trick to ressolve.
replace module to class like this [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOa1d.png) to [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anTsD.png) ....